# Wireframe not drawing with glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_LINE);

Tags: opengl

my renderer works fine if I use

```
   glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_FILL);
```

but as soon I switch to

```
   glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_LINE);
```

Nothing is drawn on screen. For some camera config I can sort of see some dots on the border of the screen, but nothing sensical.  I am doing some postprocessing on the framebuffer where the image is drawn. What can it be?

Comment: You'll need to supply a lot more information. How are you setting up your drawing? Also, what OS are you on and what type of card are you using? Is this legacy or core profile?

Comment: I'm using OGL 4.0, not core, an NVIDIA card with latest driver. I also use GLEW and GLFW

Comment: Just throwing this out there, but are you doing any kind of post processing? E.g. drawing a quad for a full screen pass which is now in wireframe?

Comment: Yes actually! How can I maintain wireframe with post-processing stuffs?

Comment: Sorry didn't tagged you @jozxyqk before

Comment: Just switch to `GL_LINE` rendering for the stuff you want drawn in wireframe and make sure to switch back before post processing.

Comment: Thank you @jozxyqk ! I can edit the question, if you post this as answer I can accept it :)